# Multiple input angular 6

Tags: angular

I am not able to send the new values ​​to the backend

Get "config" in php backend:

```
0:{id: "basic1", legend: "Basic 1", limit: 3, pos: 1}
1:{id: "basic2", legend: "Basic 2", limit: 3, pos: 2}
2:{id: "basic3", legend: "Basic 3", limit: 3, pos: 3}
```

set FormBuilder:

```
this.categoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  pos: ['', Validators.required],
  limit: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

print html:

```
<form [formGroup]="categoryForm" (ngSubmit)="saveCategory()">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of config; let i = index;" class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-1"><i class="material-icons hand" (click)="categoryExcluirOpen(categoryDelete,i)">delete_forever</i></td>
      <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="_" formControlName="pos" [value]="data.pos" maxlength="7"></td>
      <td class="col-5">{{data.legend}}</td>
      <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="_" formControlName="limit" [value]="data.limit" maxlength="7"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

save:

```
this.categoryService.saveCategory(this.config)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {});
```

I edit the values ​​they are not taken to the backend

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk5cos?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

`saveCategory()` needs to be a method that needs to be defined on your ComponentClass. It's not directly going to call your Service's method.

I'm assuming that `this.config` is going to be an object with `id` and `legend` properties on it. And you're expecting `limit` and `pos` from the form.

In your Component Class add a method named `saveCategory()`.

```
saveCategory() {
  const configToStore = {
    ...this.config,
    ...this.categoryForm.value
  }
  this.categoryService.saveCategory(configToStore)
    .subscribe(
      data => this.loading = false, 
      error => {}
    );
}
```

Comment: even though the values ​​that arrive are those that come from this.config

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Would you please consider creating a StackBlitz Project to demo the issue.